# Access position and size from Tiled object

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d-iphone and Tiled (Mac version) for creating .tmx maps.

I have an object layer with a couple objects in it.

Within the game, I need to access the X and Y position of such objects. I managed to access their property list alright, but apparently I can't get the X, Y, Width or Height at all. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your CCTMXTiledMap you get the object group like this:

```
CCTMXObjectGroup* objectGroup = [tileMap objectGroupNamed:@"myObjects"];
```

You can then iterate over the `objects` NSMutableArray or get a specific object:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [objectGroup objectNamed:@"someObject"];
```

An object is simply a dictionary that holds all the properties of the object. You can access x, y, width, height, name and type simply by using these keywords as the keys for the dictionary.

```
NSNumber* numberForX = [dict objectForKey:@"x"];
int x = [numberForX intValue];
```

Comment: Ah. I was using key "X" instead of "x". Thanks.